# Configure Jenkins to Execute tests in UFT

Tags: jenkins, hp-uft

I am running UFT Test Suite manually on the host machine, however i now have the requirement to run the smoke tests as soon as the new build is delivered in jenkins. For that i need to run the test suite automatically using Jenkings. Can someone help me in the direction, how this can be achieved? I have never used Jenkins before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like theres a plugin for Jenkins which enables integration with HP UFT.  Take a look at the [Jenkins wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HP+Application+Automation+Tools) for instructions about how to install and use it.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't mention that you are using ALM so I am assuming that you have some kind of driver script in vbs which runs your test suite. You do not necessarily require any plugin in jenkins to run your UFT suite(however you can also check the suggestion given in the previous answer). Create a job in jenkins and call your vbs file (driver file) or a bat file which kicks off your execution your test machine.
Your test execution machine can be configured as jenkins slave. Only thing which you need to take care off is to remove the settings which can let go your jenkins slave machine which is your uft execution machine in standby mode or locked user mode(uft scripts will fail otherwise). You can handle this by configuring windows settings(if admin allows) or by using some small scripts to move mouse after some intervals.
Your test execution job in jenkins(master) machine can be made dependent on the job which goes to success when new build is available. As soon as new build is available - that job goes to success then your Test job gets notified and connects to UFT execution machine(slave) and starts running your test.

Answer (score 0):

## I am trying to integrate ALM with jenkins but not working
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\JENKINSHOME\workspace\CLRP_AUTO_RN
[CLRP_AUTO_RN] $ C:\JENKINSHOME\workspace\CLRP_AUTO_RN\HpToolsLauncher.exe -paramfile props05092020010832244.txt
"Started..."
Timeout is set to: -1
Run mode is set to: RUN_PLANNED_HOST
Unable to retrieve test set folder: Node not found.
Node not found.

Starting test set execution
Test set name: CLRP Smoke Test Automation Run, Test set id: 104
Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))
Could not create scheduler, please verify ALM client installation on run machine by downloading and in installing the add-in form: http://almserver:8080/qcbin/TDConnectivity_index.html
Build step 'Execute Micro Focus functional tests from Micro Focus ALM' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE